# How to get Group of Keys based on MapEntry value by using Java 8 GroupBy

Tags: java, java-8

**we have map as below**

```
A -> Added
B -> Removed
C -> Modified
D -> Added
E -> Added
```

**expected Output:**

```
Added    = [A, D, E]
Removed  = [B]
Modified = [C]
```

We tried as below but expected output not getting

```
map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry-> entry.getValue()));
```

Please suggest me how can we get expected Output by using grouping By

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` method in combination with the `Collectors.mapping` method like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

**Outputs**

```
{Added=[A, D, E], Modified=[C], Removed=[B]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GroupingBy` works great and functionally describes the process.  But if you have a large map and want to speed things up a bit, this is somewhat faster as it does not incur the overhead of streams.

**Current Map**

```
Map<String, String> map = Map.of(
       "A", "Added",
       "B", "Removed",
       "C", "Modified",
       "D", "Added",
       "E", "Added");
```

- loop over the `entrySet` of the existing map.
- [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) checks to see if the key is present.

  - if not, it creates a list, returns it, and adds the value to the list.
  - else it returns the existing list so a new value may be added to the list.

```
Map<String, List<String>> result2 = new HashMap<>();
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> 
   result.computeIfAbsent(e.getValue(),
                          v -> new ArrayList<>())
                                .add(e.getKey()));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Added=[D, E, A]
Modified=[C]
Removed=[B]
```

If you want the original and final maps to be in a specific order based by key, use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap) for both maps.